# Generic.List of Bitmaps cant add a new Bitmap

Tags: vb.net, bitmap, generic-list

Can't add New Bitmap due NullReferenceException. What is the cause of this?

```
Dim bitmap As Bitmap = New Bitmap(10, 10)
Dim listbitmap As List(Of Bitmap)
Dim rand As Random

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For x As Integer = 0 To 9
        For y As Integer = 0 To 9
            bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black)
        Next y
    Next x
    PictureBox1.Image = bitmap
    Me.Refresh()
    listbitmap.Add(New Bitmap(bitmap)) 'error starts here
End Sub
```

Comment: You forgot `listbitmap = new List(Of Bitmap)` (`Dim listbitmap As List(Of Bitmap)` just defines the Type, it doesn't build a new object)

Comment: @Jimi its on line 2

Comment: In line 2 there's no `New` (it kind of rhymes :) You can also write: `private listbitmap As New List(Of Bitmap)`. It doesn't rhyme but at least it works.

Comment: Notice how you created a `New Bitmap` on the first line to create a new object of that type? Objects don't exist if you don't create them. Just like that, you need to create a `New List(Of Bitmap)` if you want a new object of that type. The same goes for the `rand` variable, i.e. it is `Nothing` unless you actually create an object of type `Random` and assign it to that variable.